# Algolia sorting with dynamic filter

Tags: c#, algolia

I have objects in Algolia with properties “score” (integer), “productId” (integer), and “name” (string). For example, I have two objects. First :

```
{ 
  "name": "A", 
  "productId": 1, 
  "score": 10
}
```

Second :

```
{ 
  "name": "B", 
  "productId": 2, 
  "score": 9
}
```

I’m sorting these objects based on the `“score”` field (set in Algolia dashboard => index => configuration => ranking and sorting).

Using C#, I want to pass two parameters as filter - “prodId” and “interactiveScore”. For example, if I pass `“prodId”: 1`, `“interactiveScore”: 2`, I want to subtract the “interactiveScore” from the “score”, where “productId” equals “prodId” and then order by the updated “score”. In this example, object A’s score would become 10-2 = 8, and it should be second in the search results because object B’s score is still 9. Thank you.